# What method do use when adding a jquery collection to a jQuery collection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I tried this:

```
var allItems = jQuery();

function additems(items) {
    allItems = allItems.pushStack(items);
}

additems(jQuery("#ul1").find("li").first());
additems(jQuery("#ul2").find("li").first());
additems(jQuery("#ul3").find("li").first());


allItems.each(function() {
    jQuery("ul1").append(this);
});
```

She doesn't work in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPkkT/).

What I **need** is to keep a collection of some `<LI>` items hopefully in a jQuery object. And i'd like it to use a function passing in a jQuery object. I also need to add to the collection inside a function like what I have above so it can be done at different times in the code.

i know i can get around it by something like:

```
function additems(items){
    items.each(function(){ allItems.pushStack(this);});
}
```

or by just sending them as a list of HTML `<LI>` Elements, but I'd rather do it something like the above and I haven't found a clean and efficient way of doing this.

Thanks!

*PS: I'd rather not need a plugin.*

**UPDATE**

let me explain more. I have one function that does something and it has an `<ul>` element from which i can pull out the `<li>` elements.

I then want to send these elements to another function to keep them for later.

```
function doSomething1()
{
    //Do something

    var ulElement = getFromSomewhere();
    additems(jQuery(ulElement).find("li"));

    // do something else
    return;
}

function additems(items)
{
    MyObject.allItems.pushStack(items)
}
```

the jsFiddle was Simplified compared to my code.

new jsfiddle with "#" fixed http://jsfiddle.net/LPkkT/8/

**ANSWER**

Upon adding Quincy's answer to my fiddle in a way that didn't remove all my code i got:

```
var allItems = jQuery();

function additems(items) {
    allItems = allItems.add(items);
}

additems(jQuery("#ul1").find("li").first());
additems(jQuery("#ul2").find("li").first());
additems(jQuery("#ul3").find("li").first());


allItems.each(function() {
    jQuery("ol").append(this);
});
```

And this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you want to select by id, you have to add a `'#'` in the selector.
And you can add jquery collections using the `add()` method

```
var allItems = 


jQuery("#ul1").find("li").first()
.add(jQuery("#ul2").find("li").first())
.add(jQuery("#ul3").find("li").first());


allItems.each(function() {
    jQuery("ol").append($(this));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LPkkT/4/

Comment: I need the adding to happen in a function. one at a time.

Comment: James, I think this answers your question. Think about it.

Comment: @brianpeiris Sorry i missed that bit about add able to add jQuery collections. What I needed was `allitems = allitems.add(items)`

Answer (score -1):

Can't you get the collection of items just by using a jQuery selector?
If you mark your items with a class you can get a collection with one simple selector

Comment: I need the adding to happen in a function. It has to incrementally add to the collection from another function and i don't want it directly accessing the collection.